# connecting to mysql datasource in spring boot without xml

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot

Im using some examples from the book Spring In Action 4.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("thetenticle.sql")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

The example creates a datasource which can be used to perform db operations. the example uses an embedded h2 database. this is no use to me as i want to connect to a mysql database remotely. i was hoping i could just wire in a DataSource object that has the connection details for my database. Is there a way i could do this. I dont have any interest in hibernate or xml config. im using spring boot.

Ive spent the last 18 hours trying to find a simple example that creates a mysql data source instead of an embedded h2 and sends a query to the database. i haven't found a single example of this yet. some sites suggest addingthe connection details to application.properties....but how can i create a datasource from this that i can make sql queries against?

sorry for my ignorance but i just need a simple explaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick history lesson, see below.

Do the `application.properties` setup, as mentioned in many of the examples you have seen online:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://yourhost/yourdb
spring.datasource.username=youruser
spring.datasource.password=yourpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Spring will create a `DataSource` for you, assuming you have the proper jars on your classpath.  If you are using Maven or Gradle for building your application, the following listings should help get you there.

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'
```

Finally, let AutoConfiguration build you your `JdbcOperations` object (or just your `DataSource`, if you prefer).  You don't need to do anything to have them created, just `@Autowired` them into your Spring managed beans.

```
@Component
public class MyBean {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcOperations jdbc;

    public void doJdbcStuff() {
        // use jdbc
    }
}
```

---

**History Lesson**

Early on, Spring had goals of reducing boilerplate code (just one of their many goals). They did this in many different ways, by making many API's declarative, utilizing the Template pattern, and making it easy to configure an application written in Java.  But in the process, config became a monstrosity in many large applications.  They soon realized that they had shifted much of the complexity of creating an application from the actual business part of the application to the configuration.

This is where SpringBoot comes in, with the goal of reducing ***configuration boilerplate***.  There are a handful of ways this is achieved, Bill of Materials, AutoConfiguration, and application.properties configuration are the primary means.

---

It sounds like you have been going through *Spring in Action, 4th Edition*, by Craig Walls.  If you enjoy that, and you plan on continuing to learn SpringBoot, he also penned *SpringBoot in Action*, which released late 2015.  It is a pretty quick read at 264 pages, and goes over my above history lesson a bit more thoroughly.

Comment: thans so much! i enjoyed the history lesson. i believe i had tried something very similar but without any autoconfiguration. ill try iy in the morning. it looks promising,. thanks again,  ill accept this as the answer if i get it wotking :)

Comment: thanks! Yeah I got it working this morning. I think my problem was that i had removed mysql-connector from my gradle dependencies list when i had reverted to 'trial-and-error' approach when i couldnt get it working. oops. I really appreciate your concise and informative answer :)